# Counting primitive operations using pseudocode

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, primitive, operation

How come for the first algorithm Line 2 has an operation of n-1 and for the second it is just n? What is the difference? Please explain in layman's terms I am a complete newbie.[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBinG.png)

[Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0rfW.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is one key difference in these pseudocode loops. In the first screensnip (?) the loop begins at `i=1` and ends at `i=n-1`. This means that `i` will be equal to `1, 2, 3, ..., n-2, n-1`, which is altogether `n-1` different values, hence `n-1` operations.

In the second screensnip, `i` begins at `0`, but still ends at `n-1`, so the number of different values of `i` is one larger, which is `n`.

An example for n = 4:
 First: i = 1, 2, 3. (3 = 4-1 different values) 
Second: i = 0, 1, 2, 3 (4 different values).